# Returning null values with multiple table in a query

Tags: sql, toad

I'm new to SQL and only know the very basics. I would appreciate if anyone could help on the query below. this returns all values where the fields have values however for the LO.Filurecode in need to return this where there are null values aswell to alow me to identify and populate the missing ones. can anyone help see queer below.

```
alter session set current_schema=maximo;

select
l.location,
l.description,
l.siteid,
l.type,
l.status,
lh.parent,
lo.failurecode,
lo.locpriority,
L.PLUSGSAFETYCRIT,
L.PLUSGENVCRIT,
L.PLUSGCOMCRIT,
L.PLUSGEXREGISTERED,
l.ta,
l.taqamanufacturer,
l.modelnum,
l.PLUSGLOCREFERENCE,
l.PLUSGPHYSLOC 
from
locations l, lochierarchy lh, locoper lo
where
l.location = lh.location
and l.location = lo.location
and l.siteid = lo.siteid
and l.siteid = lh.siteid
and l.type ='OPERATING'
and lh.systemid ='PRIMARY'
and l.siteid ='COA'
order by location
```

Comment: User LEFT OR RIGHT OUTER JOIN for this purpose.... This will give you blank data as well..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your query with a bit of refactoring:

```
SELECT l.location,
    l.description,
    l.siteid,
    l.type,
    l.status,
    lh.parent,
    lo.failurecode,
    lo.locpriority,
    l.PLUSGSAFETYCRIT,
    l.PLUSGENVCRIT,
    l.PLUSGCOMCRIT,
    l.PLUSGEXREGISTERED,
    l.ta,
    l.taqamanufacturer,
    l.modelnum,
    l.PLUSGLOCREFERENCE,
    l.PLUSGPHYSLOC 
FROM locations l
LEFT JOIN lochierarchy lh ON lh.location = l.location
                            AND lh.siteid = l.siteid
                            AND lh.systemid = 'PRIMARY'
LEFT JOIN locoper lo ON lo.location = l.location
                       AND lo.siteid = l.siteid
WHERE l.type ='OPERATING'
and l.siteid ='COA'
ORDER BY l.location
```

I used explicit jointure syntax (`INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN`) instead of the old school syntax you used. It's more readable and it will be easier to understand.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks Joel appreciate the help

Comment: @user4094290 If the query solves your problem, don't forget to indicate your question as `answered`

Comment: Joel can I ask one further question is it posible to include null values for the lochierarchy Table as well as there would appear to be some null values in this table also as when i check the locations table this still returns more records than in the queery.

Comment: @user4094290 I edited my query in order to allow null values from table `lochierarchy`